# google-maps: android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, google-maps

all:

I'm a new starter of android. Now I'm going to run an Android Maps V2 project. I followed step by step as described in https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw, failed and tried many times, but i continually encounter the following :

```
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapdemo/com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    ... 11 more
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.z.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.bu.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at maps.y.p.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.d$4.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:806)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1010)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1108)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4243)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
02-03 01:48:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(11547):    ... 21 more
```

Here is my project, it is very basic and short. Perhaps there's a very common mistake, but if you can point to me, I would be very grateful!

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidMenifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- End of copy. -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="xxxx"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.googlemapdemo;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;


public  MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGMap = ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private GoogleMap mGMap;
}
```

Comment: here is an how to google maps in android from Lars Vogel from beginning to end: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use `SupportMapFragment` in something other than a `FragmentActivity`. This will not work. Either convert `MainActivity` to extend `FragmentActivity`, or use `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`. The latter approach will limit your app to API Level 11 or higher.

In addition, as the stack trace tells you, you do not have the `<meta-data>` element in your manifest with your API key.

Comment: sorry, I changed to MapFragment, but the problem is still the same :(

Comment: @Flybywind: Then post the *entire* stack trace.

Comment: hi, I have updated my logs, my xml and program. hope you can find something

Comment: btw, when debugging, it stops at this line:  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 1):

This link has the steps to start gmaps v2:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Add these lines in layout, into application:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```